# Создать дубликат категории в Drupal 6

Tags: drupal

Как сделать дубликат категории товаров в Drupal 6?

Сайт: http://salongb.ru/

Там есть в категории "Окрашивание" категории Color Mask, которые нужно со всеми товарами продублировать как отдельные категории там же, в меню ниже.

Comment: никто не подскажет - может мало информации?